# Адаптер для картинок [Вопрос закрыт]

Tags: изображения

В JSON списке имеется ссылки на картинки.
Объясните, пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы при выводе отображались картинки.

Json файл имеет следующий вид:

```
{"list" : [{ "title" : "350.png", "description" : "1", "imageURL" : "URL" },{ "title" : "Dom.jpg", "description" : "2", "imageURL" : "URL" }.... и тп
```

Comment: Mother of God! Работа с интернетом в главном потоке! Руки повыдергивать!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Добавляем `uses_permission` для доступа вашего приложения в интернет:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   ```
2. Создаем класс с сеттерами и геттерами для заполнения Вашего списка:
   То есть в Вашем случае должно быть три функции для установки значений:
   `title`, `description`, `imageURL` и три соответственно для возврата  их значений.
   Создадим такой класс:

   ```
   public class MySetGetClass 
       {

       String title;
       String description;
       String imageURL;
       public MySetGetClass(String title, String description, String imageURL) {
               this.title = title;
               this.description = description;
               this.imageURL = imageURL;
       }
   ```

   // ГЕТТЕРЫ – жрицы любви

   ```
       public String getTitle() {
               return title;
       }
       public String getDescription() {
               return description;
       }
       public String getImageUrl() {
               return imageURL;
       }
   ```

   // СЕТТЕРЫ

   ```
       public void setTitle(String title) {
               this.title = title;
       }

       public void setName(String description) {

               this. description = description;
       }

       public void setImageUrl(String imageURL) {
               this. imageURL = imageURL;
       }
     }
   ```

С этим классом вроде разобрались, идем дальше!

1. Создаем свой кастомный адаптер для наполнения нашего списка.
   Т.к. стоит цель загрузки изображений из сети, а заморачиваться с этим самому большого желания нет, поэтому скачиваем библиотеку https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader и добавляем .jar файл библиотек в наш проект.
   Далее сам класс нашего адаптера.

   ```
   public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter< MySetGetClass > { 
   private final Activity activity;
   private final ArrayList< MySetGetClass > entries;
   public MyAdapter (final Activity a, final int textViewResourceId, final ArrayList< MySetGetClass > entries) {
           super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);
           this.entries = entries;
           activity = a;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           View v = convertView;
           ViewHolder holder;
           if (v == null) {
                   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                                   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                   v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ваш_лайоут_с_ImageView и двумя TextView, parent, false);
                   holder = new ViewHolder();
                   // инициализируем нашу разметку
                   holder.text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                   holder.text2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                   holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                   v.setTag(holder);
           } else {
                   holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
           }
           MySetGetClass mySetGet = entries.get(position);
           if (mySetGet != null) {
                   holder.text1.setText(mySetGet.getTitle());
                   holder.text1.setText(mySetGet.getDescrition());
                   ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
                   imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getContext()));
                   imageLoader.displayImage(mySetGet.getImageUrl(), holder.imageView);
           }
           return v;
   }
      private static class ViewHolder {
           public TextView text1;
           public TextView text2;
           public ImageView imageView;
         }
   ```

   }

Адаптер готов, пора передавать ему значения.

1. Заполнение адаптера
   В основной активности, во время парсинга, Вы убираете **HashMap** (он Вам больше не нужен) и делаете следующее:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private MyAdapter adapter;
   private final ArrayList<MySetGetClass> nutro= new ArrayList< MySetGetClass >();
   private ListView list;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
   ```

   ---

   ```
           nutro.removeAll(nutro);
           for(int i =0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject my_obj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
           title = my_obj.getString("title");
           description = my_obj.getString("description");
           imageURL = my_obj.getString("imageURL");
           MySetGetClass struct = new MySetGetClass (title,description,imageURL);
           nutro.add(struct);
           }
   ```

   ---

   ```
           list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
           adapter = new FriendsAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.id.listView1, nutro);
           lv.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
   ```

   }

Запускаем и проверяем! Вроде все.

Comment: @BTCY может и не работал, я код в блокноте писал! Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).